# Polyglot persistence in Android

Tags: android, persistence, polyglot

I wonder if there is a way of implementing [Polyglot persistence](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html) in Android.

How would you implement it?

I'm looking for an Open Source sample project in order to dig deeper into the subject.